# Find what word appeared more than once

Tags: regex, linux, string, perl, shell

I have a text file, where each line is a set of comma separated words. I need to know if a word was repeated and if so, in what lines it was repeated. Example:

```
word1, word2, word3, word4, word5
word6, word4, word7, word8
```

output:

```
word4: 1,2
```

I am experimenting with a perl script which creates a map from words to line numbers as it reads the file line by line, but I was wondering if there is a simpler approach.

Comment: Can a word appear twice on one line? e.g. `word1, word1, word2....`

Comment: @TLP: In my application, each word appears in a line only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to read all the lines before you can print anything, so what you describe is what you have to do, but it turns out to be quite simple to do.

```
my %seen;
while (<>) {
   for (split /\s*,\s*/) {
      push @{ $seen{$_} }, $.;
   }
}

for my $word (keys(%seen)) {
   next if @{ $seen{$word} } < 2;
   print($word . ": " . join(",", @{ $seen{$word} }) . "\n");
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `next unless` (or `<=`), otherwise you exclude the words with more than 1 match.

Comment: I imagine you are careful with your choices when coding Perl. What is your reason for the parentheses and dot operators in the `print` statement? I would have chosen `printf` myself.

Comment: @Borodin, Never even considered it as an option. `printf("%s: %s\n", $word, join(",", @{ $seen{$word} }));` might indeed be tiny bit clearer, although the `:` and newline stands out in the existing code.

Answer (score 2):

Using a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -F/,\s*/ -lanE 'push @{$w{$_}}, $. for @F; }{ say "$_: @{$w{$_}}" for grep {@{$w{$_}} > 1} sort keys %w' words.txt
```

**Switches**:

- `-F`: split() pattern for -a switch (//'s are optional)
- `-l`: enable line ending processing
- `-a`: Splits the line on space and loads them in an array `@F`
- `-n`: Creates a `while(<>){...}` loop for each “line” in your input file.
- `-e`: Tells `perl` to execute the code on command line. (`-E` enables all optional features)

Comment: Miller is back!  +1 because one-liners **can** be explained.